# search result via dynamic multiple dropdown list in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

please visit this link :   http://tndoctors.in/doctors.php

in that six drop down boxes are there na....
(STATE , DISTRICT , LOCATION , MEDICINE , SPECIALTY , GRADE)

I FETCHED ALL THE DATA FROM SQL DB TO  ALL DROPDOWN BOXES.

i created table  like

`STATE (state id  & state  name) [st.id as primary key]`

`DISTRICT(district id , district name and used state id as foreign key here)`

`location (location id , location name and used district id as foreign key here)`

as same above for medicine , specialty and grade..............

and at last i created a table

`DOCTOR_DETAIL ( name , address , reg.no , contact details , age , and specialty , grade , medicine , district and state)`

for specialty , grade ,medicine , district and state  i used the above tables id (primary key) as foreign key in the doctor _detail table

for example if  i select

```
 STATE: TAMILNADU
 DISTRICT: COIMBATORE
 LOCATION : some data
 medicine : allopathy
 speciality : cardiac surgeon
 grade    : some data....
```

if i select the above all things from drop down list.... and on clicking the go button...

i have to get the possible search results

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: you can use JOINS. and then in where clause put all the conditions, it will output your result.

Comment: how can  i get the possible o/p from the database...

Comment: please send the query ........or any example link.....

Answer (score 0):

Try Query like this, its Sample only

```
select  location , district , state from state as st left join district as dt on(dt.fkstate_id = st.id) left join location as lt on(lt.fkdistrictId = dt.id) where // Where condition
```